# programmatic partial submit

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-2

my form consists of following elements:

1. **icefaces text field** to enter search criteria.
2. **icefaces command button** (find) to make **partial submit** and populate a div with new list of matched users.
3. other two icefaces text fields, when submitting whole form i need their values.

**Requirement:** i want when user press enter in the text input field, that find button gets clicked (when the button gets clicked by mouse it makes partial submit automatically)

so here's what i tried:

```
<ice:inputText id="recipient" value="#{myBean.searchValue}" size="60" 
                     onkeydown="handleEnter(event,this.form);" >
                </ice:inputText>

                <ice:commandButton id="find" value="Find"  action="#{myBean.findEmployees}" partialSubmit="true"
                     >
                    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="employees" />
                </ice:commandButton>
```

- the JS method:

  ```
  function handleEnter(event,form){

     if (event.keyCode == 13){
      document.getElementById(form.name+':find').click(); 
     }
  }
  ```
- the generated ice command button:

  ```
   <input type="submit" value="Find" style="width: 60px;"     onfocus="setFocus(this.id);"     onclick="iceSubmitPartial(form, this, event);return false;" onblur="setFocus('');" name="myForm:find" id="myForm:find" class="iceCmdBtn findButton">
  ```

**ISSUE:** what happens is the when user press enter, find button is invoked, but whole form gets submitted, so a required validation error appears for the other two text fields.

please advise why whole form is getting submitted, and how to handle such issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what HTML exactly an `<ice:commandButton>` generates, but try `onclick()` instead of `click()`. It will then only fire the button's `onclick` function instead of virtually clicking the button.

Comment: @BalusC, onclick gives same behavior, i added generated code of ice command button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the enter button working fine with partial submit, i have to remove the 'required=true' tag from the inputs and make the validation with JS.

Answer (score -1):

set immediate = true on the button

Comment: Please explain your answer.